# mysql event not going off but event scheduler is on

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL event and it wont go off. I have made sure that the event scheduler is on. is there something wrong with my create event code?

```
create event POS_Data_Import.alterSalesTransactions 

on schedule 

every 1 day 

starts '2023-01-11 05:50:00' on completion preserve enable 

    do 

CALL `POS_Data_Import`.`sp_Alter_CustomerExport`(); 

CALL `POS_Data_Import`.`sp_Alter_SalesTransactionImport`();
```

Comment: BEGIN-END needed.

Comment: @Akina where do I put the begin and end?

Comment: [BEGIN ... END Compound Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html)

Comment: @Akina MySQL does not want that it throws an error. also i have tried this with just single call statements and it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure the called procedures are not failing/doing nothing? I would add an insert to debug table to show when  event fires..

Comment: Without changing the delimiter, this block is doing two things: creating an event to call sp_Alter_CustomerExport and then directly running the call to sp_Alter_SalesTransactionImport.

Answer (score 1):

Use begin...end statements around the two calls like this example:

```
delimiter //

CREATE EVENT mydatabase.myevent
    ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 MINUTE
    starts '2023-01-12 05:50:00' on completion preserve enable
    DO
    BEGIN
            UPDATE mydatabase.table1 SET inventory = inventory + 1;
            UPDATE mydatabase.table2 SET inventory = inventory + 2;
    END //

delimiter ;
```

After you do that, check that the event_definition has been created correctly:

```
select * from information_schema.events;
```

And that the event is enabled:

```
show events from mydatabase;
```

And that the event scheduler is running (the state should be "waiting for next activation"):

```
show processlist;
```

Comment: when I put the begin an end it throws an error "END is not valid at this position"
the code will not save properly in the comment unfortunately

Comment: Could you please update your original post to show the new code?